# .htaccess mod-rewrite: Modify working RewriteRule to catch any query string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following working RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^FB([^&#]+)#(?:.+\.)?([^.]+)\.$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/fb/%2/%1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

I rewrite rule catches `https://www.domain.name.info?FBxxx` but not `https://www.domain.name.info?FBxxx&id=1&pk=2`.

I would like to modify the RewriteRule to catch urls with any query string, but I don't need the other values of the query string in the final url.
So the target domain is in both cases the same:

```
any-subdomain.domain-name.info?FBabc => https://www.mysite.de/link/fb/domain-name/abc
any-subdomain.domain-name.info?FBxzy&id=1&pk=2 => https://www.mysite.de/link/fb/domain-name/xyz
any-subdomain.domain-name.info?FBghf&any-query-string-referrer-might-add => https://www.mysite.de/link/fb/domain-name/ghf
```

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^FB([^&#]+)(?:&.+)?#(?:.+\.)?([^.]+)\.$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/fb/%2/%1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Without success. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What is your target URL after redirect of  `https://www.domain.name.info?FBxxx&id=1&pk=2` ?

Comment: Thanks you your reply. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{QUERY_STRING} \.([^.]+)\.[^.#]+#FB([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/fb/%1/%2? [L,NE,R=301]
```

Note that query string must start with `FB` (case ignored).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I does not work quite right.
This works: `wwwn.domain-name.info?FBabc => https://www.mysite.de/link/fb/domain-name/abc`.
But this is redirected as follows: `wwwn.domain-name.info?FBabc&test=1 => https://www.mysite.de/link/fb/domain-name/test?FBabc&test=1`.

Comment: You can see working demo here: https://regex101.com/r/dpFspy/1 Also I have tested above rule on my Apache. Make sure this is your topmost rule and you test from a new browser.